# ¿Como agarrar un substring de una url?

Tags: php, string

Quiero tomar el id de los enlaces de google photos
Por ejemplo: https://photos.google.com/u/2/photo/AF1QipPjyBmxSA2OHAEaXVWNsG29PPBu6xiMal4LFNZ_

Yo tomé el *AF1QipPjyBmxSA2OHAEaXVWNsG29PPBu6xiMal4LFNZ_* mediante php

código

```
<?php
$url="https://photos.google.com/u/2/photo/AF1QipPjyBmxSA2OHAEaXVWNsG29PPBu6xiMal4LFNZ_";
```

Comment: Tu pregunta no es tal. Sólo veo un signo de interrogación y la formulación de un deseo. Por favor consulta [ask].

Comment: Necesitas obtener AF1QipPjyBmxSA2OHAEaXVWNsG29PPBu6xiMal4LFNZ_  mediante php?

Comment: Exacto, sabes como hacerlo?

Comment: para extraer cadenas en php debes usar [substr](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.substr) y para saber la posición en la que debes empezar la extracción debes usar [strpos](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.stripos.php) aplicado a [DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR](https://www.php.net/manual/es/dir.constants.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si necesitas extraer "AF1QipPjyBmxSA2OHAEaXVWNsG29PPBu6xiMal4LFNZ_" puedes hacer de la siguiente forma

```
$url="https://photos.google.com/u/2/photo/AF1QipPjyBmxSA2OHAEaXVWNsG29PPBu6xiMal4LFNZ_";
$string = explode('/',$url)[6];
echo $string;
```

La función Explode() te mostrar todos los elementos de $url como array y podas acceder a la posición que desees.

```
Array
(
    [0] => https:
    [1] => 
    [2] => photos.google.com
    [3] => u
    [4] => 2
    [5] => photo
    [6] => AF1QipPjyBmxSA2OHAEaXVWNsG29PPBu6xiMal4LFNZ_
)
```

Comment: Te quiero bro. Si me funciono